# Webpack and ts-loader bundle returning TypeError on third party library

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, commonjs, ts-loader

Everything compiles and bundles however there is a TypeError in the browser: "box2dweb_commonjs_1.default is undefined."
No error on starting webpack-dev-server and checking the bundle at http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/. The project is on GitHub https://github.com/paboulos/ts-loader_box2d
What is wrong with the bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> box2dweb_commonjs_1.default i

Common issue. The library doesn't export a `default`. Instead of using

```
import box2dweb from "whatever";
```

You need to use

```
import * as box2dweb from "whatever";
```

## More

The library doesn't export a default. Note that this would be a compile error if the library was written in TypeScript. People writing JavaScript are also confused about what is and what isn't a default export, so babel fixes it for them, however TypeScript doesn't.

Long term bable way of automagically making the main export also the `default` export might win the standards choice but its not the case yet so TypeScript is punting.